# Seperate Apache POST requests in another log file

Tags: logging, apache2

Need to filter all POST requests on my apache2 access.log file and write them into another log file. 
Found out apache2 mod_log_config module could do it, together with mod_setenvif.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html

Found example in the manuals

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI \.gif$ gif-image
CustomLog "gif-requests.log" common env=gif-image
CustomLog "nongif-requests.log" common env=!gif-image
```

However would really appreciate help in adapting for my need.

Example from the access.log it should match:

```
00.000.000.00 - - [07/Jun/2019:20:50:40 +0300] "POST
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SetEnvIf Request_Method "POST" posts
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/post.log common env=posts
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log common env=!posts
```

Put this in your virtual hosts(sites-available) files and restart apache2.